# Trouble with Facebook comments on Blogger platform - "Message Failed"

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, blogger, facebook-comments

I see this one has come up a couple times before on SO.

Using blogger to host at the moment until I transfer to my own URL.

I've got the plugin on my blog posts, but everytime I try to leave a comment I get "Message Failed", and then the plugin greys out.

I have debugged it using Facebook's scraper and removed duplicate URL OG references, which doesn't fix the problem.  The scraper is fine with the code now.  It ignores my og:image in favor of an image on my blog post but I can live with that.

The app itself is live.

Here's the code I am using:

```
xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
```

Above /head tag :

```
<meta content='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/blahblah.png' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta content='My blog' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
```

Below the body tag :

```
<div id='fb-root'/>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : &#39;1739492769651280&#39;,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : &#39;v2.7&#39;
});
  };

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js&quot;;
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, &#39;script&#39;, &#39;facebook-jssdk&#39;));
</script>
```

And lastly, where the plugin is supposed to appear:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div style='padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;'><script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'/>
<div>
<fb:comments colorscheme='light' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' width='700'/></div>
</div>
</b:if>
```

If anyone knows how to get past this "Message Failed" thing I'd be amazingly grateful.